# iPad Browser Simulator?

Tags: ipad, testing

How can I use a browser in Windows to simulate the iPad browser?

Comment: Related question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555005/how-can-i-emulate-ipad-browser-on-windows I use this:
http://www.electricplum.com/simulator.aspx

Comment: It's too bad questions can be closed by two people.  This question is very specific and constructive.  It is a great resource for people.  Unfortunately, I think the answer is that you can't really simulate an iPad in windows.

Comment: I have found a way to simulate an iPad in windows. Mods, please reopen this question so that I can post it as an answer. I actually do not see how this question can be *"not constructive"*.

Comment: I'm sorry, I already did that before and still gets closed, maybe you can share your answer as a comment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best approach I found is in Apple's [Technical Note TN2262: Preparing Your Web Content for iPad](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2010/tn2262/_index.html).

> 1. Test your website on iPad, and update user agent detection code if necessary
> 2. Use W3C standard web technologies instead of plug-ins
> 3. Check your viewport tag settings
> 4. Modify code that relies on CSS fixed positioning
> 5. Prepare for a touch interface
> 6. Use textareas instead of contenteditable elements

The user agent thing under the **Simulating Safari on iPad HTTP requests in Safari on the desktop** was really helpful.

Comment: How does this have anything to do with the original question? This is a link to 'best practices' for launching an ipad app.

Comment: In the original question, I asked for a browser that simulates the iPad browser. then I found these guides to configure your Safari browser to work like as if it is the iPad browser.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me. I have a specific problem in which a JavaScript code isn't working properly on my site on iPhone/iPad and I wasn't able to simulate the problem with the approach suggested on the link.

Comment: This "link" as you say, is quite useless. Changing the User-Agent header does not alter the behavior of the device or its browser at all. The User-Agent header simply tells the server it is talking to about the device and its browser.

Comment: I don't have an iPad, so I needed to simulate the iPad browser, this "Link" helped me to do it

Answer (score 3):

You're probably best off:

1. Downloading Safari for Windows.
2. Disabling plugins (e.g. Flash).
3. Resizing to the dimensions of the iPad's screen.

Safari for the desktop and Safari for iOS use the same core (WebKit), so you'll get the most reliable rendering reproduction. You'll miss the fancier zooming/relayout functionality, but for many purposes, it will probably work OK.

---

I should note for the record that Google Chrome and some other, lesser-known browsers also use WebKit, but Safari for the desktop is more likely to reproduce the results of Safari for iOS, since they're both maintained by Apple.

Comment: Interestingly this solution won't work to accurately test iPad compatibility, we've found sound Javascript issues that only occur on iOS, not in safari, and more specifically some that only occur on the ipad and not the iphone.

Comment: Moreover, in IPad version of Safari there are additional events for `touch` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Shaun Sullivan created [iBBDemo2](http://code.google.com/p/ibbdemo2/), which is an ipad/iphone simulator using Adobe Air.

It's not quite the same (e.g. elements with `overflow: scroll;` get scroll bars here, while they don't on the actual device) but it can give you a good idea of how your website would look.

Comment: I can't seem to disable flash on this demo.

Comment: iBBDemo2 link is dead

Comment: Oops! Updated it to point at http://code.google.com/p/ibbdemo2/. Looks like it's mutated into http://www.electricplum.com/studio.aspx now though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to really simulate an iPad, you need to get a real OS X, and install XCode. Virtualizing OS X is hard and not-legal. Installing Mac OS X onto a regular PC is possible, but not very legal, and you have to hack your way trough it.

Comment: I think he's talking about the iPad simulator you get with Interface Builder.

Comment: Virtualizing OS X is not illegal when you buy the OS.

Comment: It's not illegal but according to the OS X terms of service, OS X can only be installed on Apple hardware. Therefore, virtualizing OS X on a PC is breaking the TOS and likely to get into a legal quagmire if Apple knew (and cared).

Comment: Nobody said anything about virtualizing on a PC, it might be a Mac for all we know.