# how can I emulate iPad browser on Windows

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari

How can I emulate iPad browser under windows? I know user agent string and I know browser width/height, screen width/height

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe if you emulate the User Agent of the iPad and set your windows size appropriately, you can use Safari (windows download from apple.com) and works pretty cool.

Also i haven't tested this, but http://code.google.com/p/ibbdemo2/ looks like a great iPad emulator.

Comment: What's your bug? Maybe I can find something else

Comment: Some elements on my page are messed They're in wrong places At the same time rest of the page looks ok

Comment: In iBBDemo2 my page looks very similar to iPad page but to obtain the result the page have to be zoomed

Comment: I think the Safari user agent for Ipad is not working, the site look good on Safari for Window, which version of Safari use the Ipad2?

Answer (score 3):

For anybody else still looking, follow these steps for Safari 4+ : [Mobile Safari Settings on Desktop Safari](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12663/view-mobile-websites-in-windows-with-safari-4-developer-tools/)

Comment: do you know if it triggers hover events if you hover over it with your mouse. cause i need something where it doesnt, where when i click, a touch is triggered..

Answer (score 3):

It can be done via [Browser Stack](http://browserstack.com)

Answer (score 1):

> So do you guys know there is one more option and that is google
>   chrome. Yes google chrome provides developer toolbar where you can
>   inspect your element or debug your js files or you can see what are
>   the requests your site is hitting and receiving in the network panel.

It also having "Console" where you can emulate your site to different devices view.

Follow the steps below:

1. Open your site in latest google chrome.
2. Now right click and select "inspect element" or (F12) to get the devloper toolbar where you will find "Elements,Network,Sources....Console".
3. Click on console.
4. Now in the developer toolbar if you see at extreme top right you will find few options like "close the developer toolbar with cross (X) mark" but you click on "show drawer having this symbol (>-) kinda".
5. Now within the toolbar it will populate console,Search,emulation,Rendering.
6. Click on emulation option.
7. Just enable the emulation.
8. Now happily select whatever device you want and plus it will also tells you what is the resolution.

Please let me know if this is what you want and also ping me if you have any issue. You can read more [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/?hl=en).

I am enable to add image since my rating is less by "1". if I get that rating I will attach image and then it will be clear to all. The previous link has images if you want to check it out thought.

Answer (score -2):

http://transmog.net/ try this site.
I use for testing on linux.

Comment: did not work for me at all.  Layout was overlayed over their ipad framing.